# Printing messages to console from C++ DLL

Tags: c++

I have an application which uses C# for front end and C++ DLL for the logic part. I would want to print error messages on console screen from my C++ DLL even when the C# GUI is present. Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [AllocConsole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx) to create a console window and then write to standard output.

If you are using C or C++ standard I/O functions (as opposed to direct win32 calls), there are some extra steps you need to take to associate the new console with the C/C++ standard library's idea of standard output. http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm explains what you have to do and why, with complete code.

Comment: hey Greg, could you please expand on using AllocConsole(). Any links for reference?

Comment: I added a link to the MSDN documentation for AllocConsole(). It's very simple. Just call AllocConsole() to create a console window for your application and check the return value to make sure it didn't fail for some reason.

Comment: I used AllocConsole to create a console window but nothing was being printed on the screen. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I apologize, I've only used AllocConsole() from C#. It appears that there are some extra hoops you have to jump through when using C or C++ standard library I/O functions because of the abstraction layers between the functions and the win32 stdout/stdin/stderr handles. I've added a link to the answer that explains the extra steps you need to do.

Answer (score 18):

You can use OutputDebugString in C++ DLL, and then execute [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to get the messages

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly and exactly what I needed. I mean, really, THANKS.

Comment: Thanks from me too. For others: to pass a simple string, do OutputDebugString(L"test");

Comment: Alas, I only have one upvote to give this answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Unless the application is started from a console, stdin, stdout, and stderr won't even exist and any attempt to use e.g. `printf()` will fail. Either open your own console or use a debugging mechanism such as `OutputDebugString()` suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with DLLs and Service EXEs like COM/DCOM or any other ATL project, you can also use this line of code to print out diagnostic messages in the form of `MessageBox` windows as an alternative to printing messages to the console:

`MessageBox(NULL, L"Com Object Function Called", L"COMServer", MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND);`

Example cases where I have used this include the `_tWinmain` function, as well as constructors and destructors to keep track of instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ standard I/O functions you can use these two useful MACROs:

```
 _RPT1(0, "%f\n", sum);
 TRACE("The value of x is %f\n", sum);
```

Here `f` is double and the result can be viewed in [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview).

P.S.: I'm using this code in MS Visual Studio 2019 C++;