# Writing to Console from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, console, pipe

I have a DLL for a program, and want to be able to run that program in a command line, and then pipe the output of my DLL to another program.  How do I do this?

I can currently opening a new debug console to print to, but I want to be able to pipe the output so that I can run a shortcut like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "C:\Program_Using_the_DLL.exe | C:\Program_to_Pipe_To.exe"
```

This is different from some similar questions (IE:  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354138/printing-messages-to-console-from-c-dll)) in that I need to be able to pipe the output, so I need it to come to the current console.

Perhaps I can use GetStdHandle() somehow, or is there someway of using  AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)?  Any help would be appreciated!  I'm new to this nitty-gritty part.

(DLL is written in C++)

Comment: When you pipe the output of a program to another program, it isn't going to the console anymore so AttachConsole isn't going to help. You need to get the file handle being used for output by the parent program and hope it's compatible with the C++ I/O.

Comment: I see no reason why it just shouldn't work. What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the function [`GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231.aspx) to get a `HANDLE` to the current output file.

Comment: How do I then write using that file HANDLE?

Comment: Ahhh my stupidity hurts!  The correct answer is (of course), call

    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, currentConsole);

Where currentConsole is what is returned by GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE).

Comment: So, in summary: use cout << (whatever) as you normally would, but before you do all this, simply call SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE).

Comment: Also, I'd upvote if I can, but I don't have enough reputation yet!  Will try to go answer some questions of my own....